# Matlab Convolution using gpu

Tags: performance, matlab, cuda, convolution

I tried the matlab's convolution function conv2 convn with gpuArray.
For example convn(gpuArray.rand(100,100,10,'single'),gpuArray.rand(5,'single') and compared it to the cpu version convn(rand(100,100,10),rand(5)). Unfortunately the gpu version is much slower than the cpu version, especially noticeable when I put the function for example into a loop(which will be relevant for me). Does anyone know an alternative to fast convolution using matlab and the gpu for relatively small filtering kernels from 5x5 to 14x14?

Answer (score 2):

The GPU performance is limited by the data array size [100x100x10] and [5x5] in your test case.

The actual performance also depends on the GPU and CPU module type. For your data size (test case 2 of the following code), I can get a performance improvement (2.75x) on GPU Tesla M2090 and CPU Xeon E5-2609.

For the following matlab test code

```
m=1000;
n=100;
k=5;

gc=convn(gpuArray.rand(m,m,10,'single'),gpuArray.rand(k,'single'));

tic;
for i=1:n
    gc=convn(gpuArray.rand(m,m,10,'single'),gpuArray.rand(k,'single'));
end
toc

c=convn(rand(m,m,10,'single'),rand(k,'single'));
tic;
for i=1:n
    c=convn(rand(m,m,10,'single'),rand(k,'single'));
end
toc
```

When `m=1000; n=100; k=5;` I got very good performance improvement (11.6x) on GPU.

```
Elapsed time is 2.367453 seconds.
Elapsed time is 27.502952 seconds.
```

But when `m=100; n=1000; k=5;` I got only 2.75x

```
Elapsed time is 1.206053 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.330559 seconds.
```

When `m=100; n=1000; k=14;`, it becomes better (4.84x).

```
Elapsed time is 2.804957 seconds.
Elapsed time is 13.585698 seconds.
```

Comment: The example in the question is my test case 2. Case 1 has larger data size and case 3 has larger filter kernel size. So they both perform better than case 2.

Comment: Hi, Could you specify MATLAB version? I don't get why the 'conv2' performance are so bad on the GPU in Mathworks implementation.

Comment: @Drazick 2013a linux x86_64

Comment: This is so disappointing, Convolution should have much better gains on the GPU: http://www.accelereyes.com/products/benchmarks_arrayfire# What does Mathorks do wrong?

Comment: The benchmark use data "designed" for GPU - seperatable, large kernel size, large data size... Of course the result looks much better.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. I think MATLAB's code isn't optimized well. Don't you think? Less than one scale improvement for 4000x4000 image with 7x7 kernel?