# The performance of convn using GPU in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpgpu

I found a related 
 [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477224/matlab-convolution-using-gpu) in stackoverflow.

It does not solve my problem. I found that when the dimension m is small, the convn using GPU works worse than the one using CPU. I used the following test codes:

```
m=28;
n=10;
%m=100;
%n=100;
Nsample = 50;
k=5;
x1 = gpuArray.rand(m,m,Nsample,'single');
x2 = gpuArray.rand(k,'single');
tic;
for i=1:n
    gc=convn(x1 , x2 , 'valid');
end
toc

x1 = rand(m,m,Nsample,'single');
x2 = rand(k,'single');
tic;
for i=1:n
    c=convn(x1,x2,'valid');
end
toc
```

For different m value, the performance is different:

when m = 28，
    Elapsed time is 0.076827 seconds.
    Elapsed time is 0.020734 seconds.

when m = 100，
    Elapsed time is 0.086314 seconds.
    Elapsed time is 0.234197 seconds.

when m = 200，
    Elapsed time is 0.077589 seconds.
    Elapsed time is 0.243595 seconds.

It seems the Matlab could optimize the GPU code when m is small. I think maybe it depends on IO cost.

Is there any way to optimize the code when m is small ?

Thank you guys very much.

-----------------------**Extra Experiment Results (11/03/2014)**----------------------------

Hi

Thank you for all the replies.

I and my colleague have made extra experiments, and we found some extra results. In short, we observe two problems in Matlab:

1. It will take much time on **Garbage Collection**.
2. It will throw out an error when I keep allocating new variables.

### For problem 1

I used the following codes:

```
timel=[];
for i=1:10;
    m1 = 1000;    m2 = 1000;    Nsample = 50;    n=10;    k=5;
    tic;
    x1 = gpuArray.rand(m1,m2,Nsample,'single');
    x2 = gpuArray.rand(k,'single');
    clear x1 x2;
    time = toc;
    timel = [timel , time];
end
timel
```

The result is:

```
timel =   0.0646    0.0579    0.0563    0.0566    0.0572    0.0571    0.0560    0.0574    0.0573    0.0582
```

It seems that it takes a long time to collect the garbage memory space.

For the running time of CONVN, if I use the following codes, which adds the function `convn`, but the result is saved to `gc`

```
timel=[];
for i=1:10;
    m1 = 1000;    m2 = 1000;    Nsample = 50;    n=10;    k=5;
    x1 = gpuArray.rand(m1,m2,Nsample,'single');
    x2 = gpuArray.rand(k,'single');

    % running time of CONVN
    tic;        
    gc = convn(x1,x2,'valid');        
    %clear gc;
    time = toc;

    clear x1 x2;
    timel = [timel , time];
end
timel
```

The runing time is:

```
 timel = 0.0643    0.1215    0.0075    0.2517    0.0075    0.2504    0.0075    0.2500    0.0075    0.0075
```

The running time is not stable:  from `0.0075` to `0.2517`

If I uncomment the line `clear gc;`, then the running time is quite stable, as follows:

```
timel = 0.0627    0.0657    0.0634    0.0634    0.0623    0.0623    0.0629    0.0632    0.0632    0.0622
```

It indecates that then running time of `convn` is fast, but the memory collection is the bottleneck.

Does anyone know how can I use one part of fix gpu memory with out memory collection, for example, the c style code:

```
`convn(x1,x2,&gc,'valid')`
```

### For problem 2

I used the following codes:

```
%% test Memory Allocation
timel=[];
for i=1:10000;
    m1 = 1000;    m2 = 1000;    Nsample = 50;    n=10;    k=5;
    tic;
    x1 = gpuArray.rand(m1,m2,Nsample,'single');
    %clear x1;
    time = toc;
    timel = [timel , time]
end
```

The result shows that the cost time of allocating new memory is very trival, but it will raise one error after several loops：

```
Error using gpuArray.rand
An unexpected error occurred trying to launch a kernel. The CUDA error was:
the launch timed out and was terminated
Error in test (line 20)
        x1 = gpuArray.rand(m1,m2,Nsample,'single');
```

It is reasonable, since I have allocated lot of gpu memorry. But the worse thing is that, if I use

```
clear all;
```

I will get extra warning, as follows:

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT 
Warning: An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT
```

I still can not allocate new gpu memory until I reset my GPU device, using: `reset(gpuDevice())`
It seems Matlab could not track all the memory when the previous error raised, and I could not clear all the allocated memory.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use GATHER right after 'gc' calculation - http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/gather.html? I tried and the runtimes are consistent, i.e. they increase as 'm' increases.

Comment: My results (GPU runtimes only) after GATHER usage - m = 28 : Elapsed time is 0.059455 seconds. m = 100 : Elapsed time is 0.072750 seconds. m = 200 : Elapsed time is 0.108760 seconds.

Comment: If the GPU is not saturated you will not be able to reach its best performance. Your results seem to be consistent with my expectations. As long as `m` is small, the CPU performs better than the GPU. For small `m`, I don't think you will be able to outperform sequential computations for individual convolutions, because kernel launch overheads will mask the high parallelism you can achieve by the GPU. Opposite to that, if you have to calculate a large number of small convolutions, then you can use streams to saturate the GPU and in this case you will perhaps be able to achieve better results.

Comment: @Divakar We do not want to gather the gpu memory data back to cpu memory.

Comment: @JackOLantern we have made extra experiments. It seems that the cost time of `convn` is small, but the cost time of `garbage collection` in Matlab is time-consuming. Do you have any experience on this problem? It seem we have to solve this problem with C, but Matlab

Comment: For problem number 2, the reason for the out of memory is not very clear. I would expect Matlab should reuse the memory space already allocated for `x1`.