# matlab convn function GPU slower than CPU?

Tags: matlab, gpu

I test the convn on two GPU: Quadro 6000 and Titan both take longer time than cpu.

A quick test can be done in matlab:

```
maxloop=1000;
for i=1:maxloop
   output2= convn(rand(320,1), rand([6,1,300]),'full');
end

for i=1:maxloop    
    goutput2= convn(gpuArray.rand(320,1),gpuArray.rand([6,1,300]), 'full');
end
```

It takes, 0.52s on CPU, but 7s on Quadro 6000 and 15s+-  on Titan.

What I had tested:

1) If change the rand input to fixed, predefined values does not give any improvement.

2) Predefine GPU output(goutput2) doesn't help so much.

Quadro

[image: Quadro 6000]

Titan

[image: Titan]

I do run the same test as the first answer:

[Matlab Convolution using gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477224/matlab-convolution-using-gpu)

Same result obtained when m=1000; n=100; k=5;

Elapsed time is 2.367453 seconds.     %%%%GPU

Elapsed time is 27.502952 seconds.    %%%%CPU

My question is what and why my own test code is running slower on GPU?

Comment: Reading the answer that you link to, your relatively small data size does not work very well on the GPU (probably due to setup cost for each run).

Comment: Could you try with more reliable benchmarking techniques as discussed in [this solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25020990/3293881) and here - [Measure and Improve GPU Performance.](http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like question [Matlab Convolution using gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477224/matlab-convolution-using-gpu) at first glances. But after increase data size from [6,1,300] to [1000,1,1000], there is no improvement in the GPU loop. So it's not about "size" of data.

When I reshape data from [1000,1,1000] to  [1000,1000], GPU runs faster and CPU runs slower than previous test.  Code and timing are listed below:

```
clear all;

maxloop=1000;

r5=rand(5,1);
r1000=rand([1000,1,1000]); %3d array

for i=1:maxloop   
   cpu_output1= convn(r5, r1000,'full');  %3d cpu array
end

r1000=reshape(r1000,[1000,1000]);
for i=1:maxloop
   cpu_output2= convn(r5, r1000,'full'); %2d cpu array
end

gr5=gpuArray.rand(5,1);
gr1000=gpuArray.rand([1000,1,1000]);

for i=1:maxloop    
    gpu_output1= convn(gr5,gr1000, 'full'); %3d gpu array
end

gr3_1000=reshape(gr1000,[1000,1000]);
for i=1:maxloop    
    gpu_output2= convn(gr5,gr3_1000, 'full'); %2d gpu array
end
```

[image]